# Admin panel search doesn't work for a specific custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

Hello I have two custom post types which are "manga" and "bolum". I can search posts on "manga" post type perfectly but when i try to search on "bolum" post type i get results from "manga" and if I try to search second time, an error page shows up like "invalid post type".

Here is my custom post type codes from functions.php

```
    function register_bolumpost() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Bölümler', 'my_custom_post','custom' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Bölüm', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'all_items'=> _x( 'Tüm Bölümler', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Yeni Ekle', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Bölüm Ekle', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Bölümü Düzenle', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Bölüm', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Bölümü Görüntüle', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Bölüm Ara', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Bölüm Bulunamadı', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Çöp Kutusunda Bölüm Bulunamadı', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Bölüm', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Bölümler', 'my_custom_post', 'custom' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Bölüm Postu',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments'),
        'taxonomies' => array('mangalar_cat'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 7,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );  
    register_post_type( 'bolum', $args );
} 

add_action( 'init', 'register_bolumpost'); 
add_post_type_support( 'bolum', 'post-formats' );

function register_mangapost() {

    $labels2 = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Mangalar', 'my_custom_post2','custom2' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Manga', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'all_items'=> _x( 'Tüm Mangalar', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Yeni Ekle', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Manga Ekle', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Mangayı Düzenle', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Manga', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Mangayı Görüntüle', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Manga Ara', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Manga Bulunamadı', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Çöp Kutusunda Manga Bulunamadı', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Manga', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Mangalar', 'my_custom_post2', 'custom2' ),
    );

    $args2 = array(
        'labels' => $labels2,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Manga Postu',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'durum_cat', 'turler_cat', 'mangalar_cat'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post' 
    );

    register_post_type( 'manga', $args2 );

}

add_action('init', 'register_mangapost');
add_post_type_support( 'manga', 'post-formats' );
```

and here is my whole functions.php, if you need.
https://paste.ee/p/wtdsz

Comment: The `add_post_type_support()` function really should be called inside the `init` callback with your register post types, or even better in the `supports` parameter of the register post type. Are you doing this search on the front-end? Do you want to **only** search on `bolum`? As it stands now, the WordPress search searches all available post types ( pages, posts, manga, bolum, etc. ) so it will pull up anything that it thinks matches.

Comment: I want to search posts in their post type section. But when i search in 'bolum' post type section, it gets me results from 'manga' post type's posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I register multiple custom post types on the `init` hook, I don't use multiple `add_action` functions. Consider this:

```
function m_register_custom_posts() {
 register_bolumpost();
 register_mangapost();
}
add_action('init','m_register_custom_posts');
```

I would also add all your custom taxonomy function calls into this function since they fire on the  same `init` hook. You have a lot of custom functions firing on the `init` hook and you are not specifying a priority to fire the them. This can lead to problems. By putting all your custom functions that fire on the `init` hook into a single function, you control the order that the custom functions are firing.

It looks like you've got a filter set in line 91 that restricts your queries.

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'tgm_io_cpt_search' );
function tgm_io_cpt_search( $query ) {

if ( $query->is_search ) {
$query->set( 'post_type', array( 'manga') );
}

return $query;

}
```

Try removing that filter and see what happens.

Comment: that did not solved my search problem but thanks for advice sir, I edited my init hooks like you said

Comment: @MustafaSöylemez see my follow up above.

Comment: thank you so much sir, that solved my problem. thank you!

Comment: The problem with that filter is there is no `is_admin()` check. Should be `if( !is_admin() && $query->is_search ) { `